# Stub out address geocoding during RSpec unit test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, geocode, stubbing

I'm using the [geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) gem to add geocoding functionality to one of my Active Record model classes. This works great, but I don't actually want the geocoding to fire during unit tests.

I've tried stubbing out the call to geocode by adding this to my RSpec test:

> before(:each) do
>     User.stub!(:geocode).and_return([1,1])
>   end

However, when I run my tests it still appears to be calling out to geocode. What am I doing wrong?

FYI, this all works if I stub on the instance level (e.g. some_user.stub! instead of User.stub!).

Comment: are you using geocode in your app like `user = User.first` and then `user.geocode`?

Comment: Just fyi, another asset to geocode and display google maps: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails

Comment: Check out my implementation:
Gist: https://gist.github.com/1275502
My notes: http://code-snippets.paveltyk.info/snippets/80

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use stubbing on the instance level, you should use other mocking framework than RSpec’s. It's `mocha` for example (add the following to `spec/spec_helper.rb`):

```
Spec::Runner.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :mocha
end
```

http://rspec.info/documentation/mocks/other_frameworks.html

Now, you can use `any_instance` in your tests:

```
before(:each) do
 User.any_instance.stub(:geocode).and_return([1,1]) 
end
```

Comment: This works if you only care about the return value of :geocode.  But the geocoder module actually updates the latitude and longitude of the object.  How would I stub that out?

Comment: In fact, the code you gave works with RSpec >= 2.6, but not with Mocha.

Comment: @harrism a little late, but I decided to approach it like this, stubbing latitude and longitude in addition to the main geocode method:

`Restaurant.any_instance.stub(:geocode).and_return([1, 1])`
`Restaurant.any_instance.stub(:latitude).and_return(1)`
`Restaurant.any_instance.stub(:longitude).and_return(1)`

Answer (score 3):

it's

```
before(:each) do 
  Address.any_instance.stubs(:geocode).returns([1,1])
end
```

with mocha.