# How to create a stub that applies to all spec files in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm wanting to know if there is an easy way to include a stub in all of my spec files. I'm using the [Geocoder gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) and when I run my RSpec tests I don't want it attempting to download the location information.

I've found the [following solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5646130/467546) which works perfectly. However, I don't want to write the same three lines in every spec file.

```
before(:each) do
  User.any_instance.stub(:geocode) { [1,1] }
end
```

Is it possible to put something in my `spec_helper.rb` file?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can put it in the spec_helper instead, like this:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each) do
    User.any_instance.stub(:geocode) { [1,1] }
  end
end
```

Comment: I added it to the bottom of my `spec_helper` file but I'm getting an undefined method `stub` error. Any ideas?

Comment: In that case add it to to the config block. See my updated answer.

Comment: That's pretty awesome! Thanks